# how to load breeze entity from local storage websql

Tags: breeze

I don't have access to an OData provider just a simple REST api with json and I need to store the data locally (on the mobile device websql) in different tables reflecting the backend model. Following the Edmunds example I have got the entity and the relationships working from the REST api. How can I make it work the same way from the data stored locally. I would like to fetch the data from the local DB and recreate my entities, any advice would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have queried the data thru the REST api, just export the EntityManager to local storage.  Something like this

```
     var changesExport = myEntityManager.exportEntities();

     ok(window.localStorage, "this browser supports local storage");
     var stashName = "arbitrary name for storage area"";

     window.localStorage.setItem(stashName, changesExport);
```

This data can later be reimported into any existing EntityManager, and then queried locally by simply reimporting the data.

```
     importedData = window.localStorage.getItem(stashName);

     anotherEntityManager.importEntities(importedData);
```

Comment: The StashName seem to store everything as a serialised object, is there a way to keep a row by row and table separation on the data stored ? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Not really, unless you want to store entity by entity.  The exportEntities call can be passed a list of entities if you want.  Take a look at the Breeze API on the website.

Comment: OK thanks (I am very new to Breeze) Does that mean that by default I should always have the hole DB in memory at all times so that i can query on it ? Can this become an issue with big data sets on a mobile support ? I am working on a barcode reader app with about 40000 products, I am wondering about the memory and the response time. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Without understanding your app, I really couldn't say. But... in general, storing 10's of thousands of records on your local machine sounds like a bad idea.  But again, I don't really know your use case.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that we need to have the app work in a "de-connected from the internet" mode. I suppose we could have Breeze monitor only the Object that need to be edited/created and the rest in the websql tables. Does that seems viable ?

Comment: Sure, and you can always retrieve data from websql and use this data to create entities in Breeze and then call "acceptChanges" on them, effectively making them look like unchanged entities ( i.e. already existing entities).